# Looping over list of vectors to create histograms for each vector

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

I am working on creating histograms for output data from a CFD simulation.

Since output variables are a lot more than one, I want to loop over the list containing output variables and create separate figure for each histogram of output variable.

Here is a sample code of my working thus far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# set default directory and import data

path="C:/Users/Pacman/Data files"
os.chdir(path)
data =np.genfromtxt('MCS_10000cases_Sc_B.txt')

#Create output vectors

Power=data[:,][:,9]
Per_Lk=data[:,][:,10]
VFR_Fan=data[:,][:,11]
VFR_MF=data[:,][:,13]
TP=data[:,][:,14]

#Plotting histgram

numbins=40
var=['Power','Per_Lk','VFR_Fan','VFR_MF','TP']

for i in var:
    plt.hist(i,numbins,color='g')
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
```

When I run the code shown above it gives me a long error which ends with the following statement:

> TypeError: len() of unsized object

When I try to plot histograms one by one without the loop it works fine. I've tried looking up the error and implement some fixes but it didn't help.

Any ideas for the fixes will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
var = {'Power': data[:,][:,9],
       'Per_Lk': data[:,][:,10],
       'VFR_Fan': data[:,][:,11],
       'VFR_MF': data[:,][:,13],
       'TP': =data[:,][:,14],
       }
numbins = 40

for i in var:
    plt.hist(var[i], numbins, color='g')
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You could have obtained the same result by introducing a slight tweak in your original code, namely ``plt.hist(eval(i), numbins, color='g')``, but I think it's preferable not to use the function ``eval()`` in this particular case.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! Although I still cannot understand what wasn't  the variable 'i' referring to vectors 'var' in my code. It will be great if you can elaborate a bit on this.

Comment: In your original code ``var`` is a list of strings, and therefore the index variable ``i`` has the value ``'Power'`` in the first iteration, ``'Per_Lk'`` in the second, and so forth, whereas in my solution ``var`` is defined as a dictionary, so that ``i`` takes exactly the same values throughout the for loop as in your code, and ``var[i]`` refers to the corresponding data.